# C# conditional appearance of properties in propertyGrid when editing multiple objects

Tags: c#, properties, propertygrid

Just stumbled upon propertyGrid and its awesome! However, i have one task that i cant find how to do with it:

I have a class which has a type. Based on type, it has different properties available. I keep it in one class (not multiple inherited classes) for simplicity sake (there are ten types but they mostly have the same properties).

For example, i have a class MapObject which can have string type equal "player" or "enemy". For "enemy", property "name" is used, but for "player" it is blank (not used).

When i select two objects, one of which is of type "player" and other of type "enemy", i want property "name" to only "count" for the "enemy". So, i want propertyGrid to show the name of the object that has type="enemy", and when it (name property) is changed in Grid, only assign it to the object of type "enemy".

Is this possible to do?

Comment: So just to clarify, the class changes depending on the data in some of the properties?

Comment: I'd like it to behave as if the object that doesnt use the property just wasnt selected for all purposes of propertyGrid object.

Comment: Lets make a very simple example. ClassA has three properties i,x,y and if i=1 then x is used and y isnt used, if i =2 then x and y are used. Lets assume o1.i=2 o1.y=1, o2.i=2 o2.y=2, o3.i=1. If i select o1 and o2, propertyGrid will show blank for y property since o1 has different y property than o2. Thats okay. But i want it to show o1.y property if i select o1 and o3, and i want it to apply changes to the y property only to o1 in this case

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a design pattern known as the state pattern. It is pretty easy to implement and you do not need property grids. http://www.dofactory.com/Patterns/PatternState.aspx

Comment: I studied it and there is a problem. Since this is a class being property of a class, it will show as such in propertyGrid - nested in a kind of "folder" which is not at all desired. Is there a way around it?

Answer (score 1):

Depending on whose PropertyGrid you are using, toggling the Browsable attribute may do what you want. See my [answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47836429/1518546) for how to do that at runtime.

If, like me, you are using the [Xceed PropertyGrid](https://github.com/xceedsoftware/wpftoolkit/wiki/PropertyGrid) then only changing the Browsable attribute at runtime once the control has loaded doesn't do anything. Instead, I also had to modify the PropertyDefinitions collection. Here is an extension method for doing that:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Show (or hide) a property within the property grid.
    /// Note: if you want to initially hide the property, it may be
    /// easiest to set the Browable attribute of the property to false.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="pg">The PropertyGrid on which to operate</param>
    /// <param name="property">The name of the property to show or hide</param>
    /// <param name="show">Set to true to show and false to hide</param>
    public static void ShowProperty(this PropertyGrid pg, string property, bool show)
    {
        int foundAt = -1;
        for (int i=0; i < pg.PropertyDefinitions.Count; ++i)
        {
            var prop = pg.PropertyDefinitions[i];
            if (prop.Name == property)
            {
                foundAt = i;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (foundAt == -1)
        {
            if (show)
            {
                pg.PropertyDefinitions.Add(
                    new Xceed.Wpf.Toolkit.PropertyGrid.PropertyDefinition()
                    {
                        Name = property,
                    }
                );
            }
        }
        else
        {
            if (!show)
            {
                pg.PropertyDefinitions.RemoveAt(foundAt);
            }
        }
    }
```

In case the above does not work for you, the following may work better and is  simpler anyway.  It also doesn't use deprecated properties like the code above did...

```
    public static void ShowProperty(this PropertyGrid pg, string property, bool show)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < pg.Properties.Count; ++i)
        {
            PropertyItem prop = pg.Properties[i] as PropertyItem;

            if (prop.PropertyName == property)
            {
                prop.Visibility = show ? System.Windows.Visibility.Visible : System.Windows.Visibility.Collapsed;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I made it with my own custom attribute:

```
public class VisibilityAttribute : Attribute
{
    public bool IsVisible { get; set; }

    public VisibilityAttribute(bool isVisible)
    {
        IsVisible = isVisible;
    }
}
```

Then my data model:

```
 public abstract class BaseSettings: INotifyPropertyChanged
 {
    public void SetVisibilityProperty(string propertyName, bool isVisible)
    {
        var theDescriptor = TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(this.GetType())[propertyName];

        var theDescriptorVisibilityAttribute = (VisibilityAttribute)theDescriptor.Attributes[typeof(VisibilityAttribute)];
        if (theDescriptorVisibilityAttribute == null) return;

        theDescriptorVisibilityAttribute.IsVisible = isVisible;
    }

    #region INotifyPropertyChanged
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private void NotifyPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] String propertyName = "")
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
    #endregion
}

public class ThrottleSettings : BaseSettings
{
    private ThrottleType _throttleType = ThrottleType.SmartThrottle;
    [PropertyOrder(1)]
    public ThrottleType ThrottleType
    {
        get
        {
            return _throttleType;
        }
        set
        {
            if (value == ThrottleType.FullThrottle)
            {
                SetVisibilityProperty(nameof(FullThrottleTimeInMilliseconds), true);
                SetVisibilityProperty(nameof(ThumbnailThrottleTimeInMilliseconds), false);
            }
            else if (value == ThrottleType.SmartThrottle)
            {
                SetVisibilityProperty(nameof(FullThrottleTimeInMilliseconds), false);
                SetVisibilityProperty(nameof(ThumbnailThrottleTimeInMilliseconds), true);
            }
            else if (value == ThrottleType.NoThrottle)
            {
                SetVisibilityProperty(nameof(FullThrottleTimeInMilliseconds), false);
                SetVisibilityProperty(nameof(ThumbnailThrottleTimeInMilliseconds), false);
            }

            _throttleType = value;
        }
    }

    private int _fullThrottleTime = 100;
    [PropertyOrder(2)]
    [Visibility(false)]
    [Description("Specifies full throttle time (in milliseconds).")]
    public int FullThrottleTimeInMilliseconds
    {
        get
        {
            return _fullThrottleTime;
        }
        set
        {
            if (value < 0) return;
            _fullThrottleTime = value;
        }
    }

    private int _thumbnailThrottleTime = 0;
    [PropertyOrder(3)]
    [Visibility(true)]
    [Description("Specifies thumbnail throttle time (in milliseconds).")]
    public int ThumbnailThrottleTimeInMilliseconds
    {
        get
        {
            return _thumbnailThrottleTime;
        }
        set
        {
            if (value < 0) return;
            _thumbnailThrottleTime = value;
        }
    }
}
```

Finally I subscribed to 'propertyGrid_PropertyValueChanged' event and call there my method:

```
private void _propertyGrid_PropertyValueChanged(object sender, PropertyValueChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        RefreshVisibility(_propertyGrid.Properties);
    }
```

Here is method itself:

```
private void RefreshVisibility(IList properties)
    {
        foreach (PropertyItem property in properties)
        {
            var visibilityAttribute = GetVisibilityAttribute(property);
            if (visibilityAttribute != null)
            {
                if (visibilityAttribute.IsVisible)
                    property.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
                else
                    property.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
            }

            RefreshVisibility(property.Properties);
        }
    }
```