# dont show property when many object selected C# property grid

Tags: c#, .net, properties, attributes, propertygrid

I know how to prevent a property from being shown in the property grid by using this attribute
`[Browsable(false)]`

but I want to prevent this property from being browsed only when there are more than 1 object selected in the property grid.

I mean that when only one object is selected in the property grid this property will be shown but when 2 or more objects are selected this property won't be browsable!

Answer (score 0):

Note: I haven't done it myself, but according to the documentation...

Have you tried `BrowsableAttributes`, documented [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.propertygrid.browsableattributes%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)? In your selection code you could probably change the `propertyGrid.BrowsableAttributes` to reflect if it's a "solo" selection or "multiple" selection, and by tagging the variables accordingly, you should be able to have the display you're looking for.

[This thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4690481/conditional-browsable-attribute) can probably help you!