# Is there anyway to make certain fields automatically disappear from PropertyGrid when multiple objects selected?

Tags: c#, .net, propertygrid

For example, when I choose multiple elements in Visual Studio form designer the field "Name" disappears from PropertyGrid.

I need to do the same for some of the fields in my classes.

How I can do that?

Comment: Not sure if [that answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13673166/dont-show-property-when-many-object-selected-c-sharp-property-grid) did help, so I'm not calling it the duplicate it is..