# C# .Net 4.5 PropertyGrid: how to hide Properties

Tags: c#, .net, properties, propertygrid

The problem is simple(and I hope that this have a simple solution!): I want to hide ( Browsable(false) ) the property "Element" (in my PropertyGrid object) when it's zero.

```
    public class Question
    {
       ...

      public int Element
      {
        get; set;
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

What you could do is reuse the `DynamicTypeDescriptor` class described in my answer to this question here on SO: [PropertyGrid Browsable not found for entity framework created property, how to find it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16422844/propertygrid-browsable-not-found-for-entity-framework-created-property-how-to-f)

like this for example:

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    DynamicTypeDescriptor dt = new DynamicTypeDescriptor(typeof(Question));

    Question q = new Question(); // initialize question the way you want    
    if (q.Element == 0)
    {
        dt.RemoveProperty("Element");
    }
    propertyGrid1.SelectedObject = dt.FromComponent(q);
}
```

Answer (score 32):

The easiest way to hide a property in PropertGrid and in a Custom Control for me is this:

```
public class Question
{
   ...
  
  [Browsable(false)]
  public int Element
  {
    get; set;
  }
}
```

To do it dynamically you can use this [code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31321637/changing-browsable-attribute-at-runtime-c), where Question is your class and your property is Element, so you can show or hide it without remove element from collection:

```
PropertyDescriptorCollection propCollection = TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(Question.GetType());
PropertyDescriptor descriptor = propCollection["Element"];

BrowsableAttribute attrib = (BrowsableAttribute)descriptor.Attributes[typeof(BrowsableAttribute)];
FieldInfo isBrow = attrib.GetType().GetField("browsable", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);
//Condition to Show or Hide set here:
isBrow.SetValue(attrib, true);
propertyGrid1.Refresh(); //Remember to refresh PropertyGrid to reflect your changes
```

So to refine the answer:

```
public class Question
{
   ...
   private int element;
   [Browsable(false)]
   public int Element
   {
      get { return element; }
      set { 
            element = value; 
            PropertyDescriptorCollection propCollection = TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(Question.GetType());
            PropertyDescriptor descriptor = propCollection["Element"];
    
            BrowsableAttribute attrib = (BrowsableAttribute)descriptor.Attributes[typeof(BrowsableAttribute)];
            FieldInfo isBrow = attrib.GetType().GetField("browsable", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);
            if(element==0)
            {
              isBrow.SetValue(attrib, false);
            }
            else
            {
              isBrow.SetValue(attrib, true);
            }
          }
   }
}
```

Comment: This is not dynamic, doesn't work at runtime, so it doesn't answer the question.

Comment: You can set the Browsable attribute at runtime, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/47836429/1518546

Comment: How to do this dynamically?

Answer (score 0):

Try BrowsableAttributes/BrowsableProperties and HiddenAttributes/HiddenProperties:

[More info here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/13342/Filtering-properties-in-a-PropertyGrid)

Answer (score 0):

When I wanted solve this problem many years ago, as I remember, attribute [Browsable] not works. I see that it works now great, but I also I made solution by way of creating proxy objects.

There is code:
https://github.com/NightmareZ/PropertyProxy

You can highlight required properties with attribute and then create proxy object which will forward only highlighted properties to PropertyGrid control.

```
public class Question
{
   ...
  
  [PropertyProxy]
  public int Element
  {
    get; set;
  }
}

...

var factory = new PropertyProxyFactory();
var question = new Question();
var proxy = factory.CreateProxy(question);
propertyGrid.SelectedObject = proxy;
```