# typeof() works, GetType() doesn't works when retrieving property

Tags: c#, reflection

I am trying to retrieve a value of `private` property via reflection

```
// definition
public class Base
{
    private bool Test { get { return true; } }
}
public class A: Base {}
public class B: Base {}

// now
object obj = new A(); // or new B()

// works
var test1 = typeof(Base).GetProperty("Test", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
if(test1 != null) // it's not null
    if((bool)test1.GetValue(obj, null)) // it's true
        ...

// doesn't works!
var test2 = obj.GetType().GetProperty("Test", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
if(test2 != null) // is null !
    ...
```

Where is my mistake? I will need to use `object` to pass instance, because some of `private` properties will be declared in the `A` or `B`. And even hiding (with `new`) `Base` properties sometimes.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Test is private to Base. It is not visible to the inherited A/B classes. You should make it `protected` if you want it visible to the inheriting class.

Or you can use `GetType().BaseType` if the inheritance tree is just one level.

```
public class Base
{
    private bool Test { get { return true; } }
    protected bool Test2 { get { return true; } }
}
public class A : Base { }
public class B : Base { }

[TestMethod]
public void _Test()
{
    object obj = new A(); // or new B()         

    Assert.IsNotNull(typeof(Base).GetProperty("Test", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic));
    Assert.IsNotNull(typeof(Base).GetProperty("Test2", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic));

    Assert.IsNull(typeof(A).GetProperty("Test", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic));
    Assert.IsNotNull(typeof(A).GetProperty("Test2", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic));

    Assert.IsNull(typeof(A).GetProperty("Test", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.FlattenHierarchy));
    Assert.IsNotNull(typeof(A).GetProperty("Test2", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.FlattenHierarchy));

    Assert.IsNull(obj.GetType().GetProperty("Test", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic));
    Assert.IsNotNull(obj.GetType().GetProperty("Test2", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic));

    Assert.IsNotNull(obj.GetType().BaseType.GetProperty("Test", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic));
    Assert.IsNotNull(obj.GetType().BaseType.GetProperty("Test2", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic));

}
```

Comment: Making `Test` `protected` helps, I didn't even think about this. Was making it `private` just to *hide* it and `protected` works same good. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

`A` inherits from `Base`, so you need to tell `GetProperty` to look for properties in the base class as well. Pass the `FlattenHierarchy` flag as well:

```
GetProperty("Test", BindingFlags.Instance 
      | BindingFlags.NonPublic 
      | BindingFlags.FlattenHeirarchy)
```

Comment: from [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.bindingflags(v=vs.110).aspx): `FlattenHierarchy: Specifies that public and protected static members up the hierarchy should be returned.`  `Test` is not public or protected so this is not gonna work

Comment: For `private` properties it does **not** helps at all. For `protected` it works even without specifying `FlattenHierarcy`.